# Diagonal drawn by using CSS3 gradient renders bad in Chrome on windows

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a website and the contact section of the website on larger screens is basically divided onto two sections and separated by a diagonal which I created using CSS3 gradient properties. It render great on Mozilla Firefox. But when I hover on the contact link the diagonal seems to shift a little bit. The effect is significantly small but it can be seen. Have I hit a Chrome based bug? Or is there something which I can't figure out?
[image: This is the rendering issue screenshot. The render problem has been highlighted.]
[The link to the site](http://rohanchhabra.in/)

Comment: Works on my Chrome..

Comment: Which OS are you on?